# Storing Ed25519 Private key on Android

Tags: java, android, public-key-encryption, ed25519

I am working on a java sdk which will be used for encryption/decryption of different data/messages and much more. It uses BouncyCastle v1.68 library, as well as Ed25519 algorithm for signing.

One of the requirements is to store Ed25519 private key. Since the sdk will be used for Android development as well, I need to expose api for storing of this type of the key on the Android platform.

Based on Android keystore system documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore, it looks like it cannot be used for storing of Ed25519 Private Key.

I do not have a lot of experience with Android development, therefore I would really appreciate proposals on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: did you find a solution for that? I need to do a similar thing, but it seems the only way is to store the private key somewhere maybe local file encrypted and then use KeyStore to generate another "supported" key to decrypt and encrypt the private key of ed25519

Comment: What I found as possible options is, the one that you explained or just storing the key in raw format in the sqlite.